# Not all nodes are utilized in spark job

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am running spark-submit in cluster mode with yarn on hadoop. This is all from apache. I tried the PI java example and found that of 4 spark slave nodes only one was used to do the actual computation(one one node had a log file and the output for the value of pi).

Trying another python app I found that only two nodes at a maximum were being used. That is two out of a maximum of four.

Is this normal behavior, or am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the screen shot of spark ui ? about your findings get a feel of what was missing and also your spark-submit job parameters as well

Comment: Yeah its normal assuming you do not have enough data to keep one node busy, the other one does not come into picture.

Comment: I'll go with what Sri Amit Kumar has said, second question: What does it mean when spark on yarn works in client mode but not in cluster mode? Please help. I am using a python script and get the expected result in client mode, job fails in cluster mode, logs only show: ERROR ApplicationMaster: User application exited with status 1